# dceTask keep is not preserving defined classes

Tags: kotlin-js

I am building a Kotlin/JS project that will be used as a library for a web app. The kotlin plugin recently enabled DCE and provides a keep directive, but it is not keeping the class I am specifying.

```
kotlin.target.browser {
dceTask {
    keep 'BluetoothSerialJs.com.fivestars.bluetooth.BluetoothSerial'
}
}
```

And here is the top of my class definition:

```
package com.fivestars.bluetooth



object BluetoothSerial {
```

Full project is here:

https://github.com/darran-kelinske-fivestars/cordova-alternative-pattern/blob/master/BluetoothSerialJs/build.gradle#L14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I needed to specify the root project name with the keep definition:

CordovoaAlternativePattern is the root project name. The root project name is typically in `settings.gradle`

So the syntax needs to be:

```
RootProjectName-ModuleName.namespace.Class
```

Full example:

```
kotlin.target.browser {
    dceTask {
        keep  'CordovaAlternativePattern-BluetoothSerialJs.com.fivestars.bluetooth.BluetoothSerial'
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is needed, but it did fix my problem.

Comment: as a work-around, can disable dead code elimination: runDceKotlinJs.dceOptions.devMode = true